# UI Bootstrap affects the rendering of my AngularJS app

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I added UI Bootstrap (latest version 2.5.0) using:

```
bower install angular-bootstrap
```

My app uses **AngularJS 1.6.9** and **Bootstrap 3.3.7**
When I added `ui-bootstrap` to the `app.js`:

```
angular.module('clientApp', ['ngRoute', 'angular-jwt', 'ui-bootstrap']);
```

> the rendering of the page (logon.html) is messed up: controls
>   (username/password, etc.) disappear, the Sign In link is rendered as
>   an Angular expression ({{userDisplayName}}), etc.

If I remove `ui-bootstrap`, everything returns to normal.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you add `ui-bootstrap` file as script source?

Comment: I assume you include `bootstrap.min.css` in your html, right?

Comment: If you're seeing {{userDisplayName}}, it means you have an error. Open your browser console and read it.